# Reordering an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
var array = [
{
    name :  "Bob",
    score : 27
},
{
    name :  "Fred",
    score : 32
},
{
    name :  "Brad",
    score : 43
}
]
```

All items are initially ranked by score. At some points, the score can change and I'd like to reorder the array.

The way I am doing it right now is I remove the player from the array, I update the score and then I loop through the array to find the right position to insert it (as the rest of the array is still sorted).

Is there a more elegant way to do it, using underscore.js for example?

Thanks

Comment: Underscore can do this trivially with `_.sortBy(array, 'score')`. Does that qualify as elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort using a `sortBy` function, something like:

```
function sortBy(f, xs) {
  var compare = function(x, y) {
    return typeof x == 'number' ? x - y
      : x > y ? 1
      : x < y ? -1
      : 0;
  };
  return xs.sort(function(x, y) {
    return compare(f(x), f(y));
  });
};
```

Then use it like:

```
sortBy(function(x){return x.score}, array);
```

Or with an additional helper for reusability:

```
function dot(x) {
  return function(xs) {
    return xs[x];
  }
}

sortBy(dot('score'), array);
sortBy(dot('name'), array);
...
```